# rowClick not firing in react-tabulator

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am using react-tabulator in my project and want to redirect the user to a different page when they click a row.

I am rendering the component like this

```
<ReactTabulator
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            layout={"fitColumns"}
            options={options}
        />
```

and my options is this (for now):

```js
const options = {
            invalidOptionWarnings: false,
            debugInvalidOptions: false,
            movableRows: true,
            rowClick: (e, row) => {
                alert("row clicked");
            }
        };
```

That code is similar to the code in [the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mwpy612xw?module=/src/components/Home.js) and the code found in the [4.9 tabulator docs](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9?#callbacks) (react-tabulator is using tabulator-tables version 4.9). When I click a row, the function is not called and no alert is shown.

I have also tried adding it as a prop to the component its self like this:

```
<ReactTabulator
            data={sounds}
            columns={columns}
            layout={"fitColumns"}
            options={options}
            rowClick={(e, row) => {alert("row clicked")}
        />
```

and that didn't work either.

It seems like I am missing something obvious, but I can't find it.

**EDIT:** To fix this I just added another column with an edit button in it.

Comment: I have been checking and it seems like all the examples are coming with Components and non hooks

Comment: @olscode What does that mean? Sorry, I'm kinda a noob in react.

Comment: its a good example to start: https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/master/src/ReactTabulatorExample.tsx If you re starting I recommend you others table easy to start

Comment: @olscode That example uses `rowClick={this.rowClick}`. That doesn't work for me. in fact `this` is undefined for me. as stated in the question `rowClick={rowClick}` also doesn't work.

Comment: have in mind that you cant use 'this' when you are using functional comps in react this is only allowed when you are using React Class. You can read more: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @olscode thats what I thought. so is this not working because I'm using functional comps?

Answer (score 1):

For rowClick we can use tabulator events.

```
const rowClick = (e: any, row: any) => {
   console.log(e, row);
};
<ReactTabulator
     data={data}
     columns={columns}
     layout={"fitColumns"}
     options={options}
     events={{
       rowClick: rowClick,
     }}
 />
```